# Where do I place a Docker file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Just got started with Docker and installed Docker Desktop for Mac. It's all a bit confusing what this does, but it seems the GUI does not support creating/viewing images/containers?

So I started creating a docker file manually, but where do I place it? `var/lib/docker/` is what people say, but that folder does not exist, although CLI says I already have to containers (created as a test after installation of the Desktop app).

**Update:** Installed Kitematic alongside the Desktop app through which I can view/create containers.

Comment: the dockerfile usually goes in the same folder as the highest object in your tree thats part of the proejct you want to add (but basically you can put it anywhere)

Answer (score 2):

I like to put it in the root of the project, but you can put it anywhere and use the `-f/--file` argument for `docker build` to specify where it's located.

Comment: Now, when I create a container using Kitematic, where are those located on my filesystem?

Comment: the cotnainer has its own file system it wont be directly repressented on your host drive

Answer (score 1):

You place to Dockefile in the root of project. Dockerfile has context it means it can copy/add files/directories which are sibling/children of its Directory.